# Relaxation Oscillator circuit analysis

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, oscillator

I'm trying to find the output expression of a relaxation oscillator in the Laplace domain, to then convert it to the time domain to be able to trace its output. However, my circuit analysis isn't giving me an expression for 
\$V_o\$. Here is the circuit that I am trying to analyze as well as the work I've done so far.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZWv3H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\begin{align}
V^- &= \frac{\frac{0}{\frac{1}{Cs}}+ \frac{V_o}{R}}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{Cs}}+ \frac{1}{R}} = \frac{V_o}{CRs+1}  \tag{Millmans}\\[0.7em]
V^+ &= \frac{\frac{0}{6k}+ \frac{V_o}{6k}}{\frac{1}{6k}+ \frac{1}{6k}} = \frac{V_o}{2}  \tag{Millmans} \\[0.7em]
V^+ &= V^- \\[0.7em]
\frac{V_o}{2} &= \frac{V_o}{CRs+1} \\[0.7em]
1 &= \frac{2}{CRs+1}\\
\end{align}

As you can see, \$V_o\$ gets canceled.

Could someone please help me find where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't still deciphered the logic behind the equations which have reference = (Millmans). Here are surely more persons than me only who want to understand the knot you have built. Maybe you can write more of it.

Comment: @user287001 Basically, Millmans theorem says that the voltage at a junction is equal to the voltages of all the branches leading to it. http://www.learningelectronics.net/vol_3/chpt_8/8.html

Comment: That's OK and gives a meaning to Vo. But the assumption of the existence of a stable state where V+=V- is nonsense. Such stable state is nonexistent. You have proved it by deriving a contradiction if you assume also that Vo should be nonzero. Vo=0 is labile like a standing needle.

Comment: @user287001 I think that my mistake is saying V+ = V-, which only works for opamps in linear mode.

Answer (score 2):

Ouch! The opamp is used in non-linear mode. Linear opamp circuit calculation practices nor transfer functions are not applicable for it.

You should divide this to a Schmitt-trigger and a charging and discharging RC circuit. Then you can find how long it takes for the RC circuit to charge and discharge between the tresholds of the Schmitt-trigger.

**ADD** you have explained the idea of your calculation properly in the comments. You wrote an equation for the condition that the opamp regenerates from the feedback voltages whatever it happens to output and stays at the same time in linear mode. The equation has two solutions

1) the output voltage Vo = 0 constantly

2) s=1/(RC)

Solution 1 is the highly unstable balance where an ideal opamp would give 0V. It's like a needle standing on its sharp tip - a theoretical only possibility.

Refining solution 2 in s-domain is beyond my math knowledge, but it obviously presents something which allows a class of infinitely growing exponential functions. It's not an explicit formula for the output voltage but a criteria for possible voltage functions just like the oscillation criteria of a sinewave oscillator would give the possible oscillation frequency or frequencies.

The explanation  for solution 2 can be found easily in time domain as a limit process where the gain of the opamp grows to infinite. The possible solutions for Vo are all exponentially growing voltages A*exp(t/RC) where A is the intial value - positive or negative or zero. Due the high gain a little noise in the input kicks the calculated Vo beyond the clipping limit, so it's purely theoretical.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Im just wondering, why do you say that s=1/(RC) ?

Comment: Find it by solving s from your equation where Vo had vanished from. I write more to the answer.

Comment: But isn't \$s\$ always the Laplace operator (\$ j\omega\$) ?

Comment: The Laplace transform variable s can in Laplace transforms get any complex value. The solution s=1/(RC) can be interpreted (I guess, cannot prove) that only exponentially growing output voltages  can exist in the valid linear range, the only possible time constant is=RC. Time domain state variable equation gives the same result without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

for **dt= C*dV / Ic** for the Cap step response time initially then exponential decay.
R divider ratio = **k = 1/2** in this example
**dV = 2k  * |Vo (max)| = |Vo_max|** is the triangle swing to the comparator Vpp
**dt = T = RC = 1/2f** =  the triangle ramp time only for 64% asymptote and not k=1/2 of the Vmax output.

C is the capacitor value

thus you can compute T.

Although slightly exponential the ramp is more linear with a smaller k like 1/4 to 1/10 which increases the frequency.

The more popular solution is to use a single supply Schmitt Logic gate or inverter and add RC with 1/3 Vdd internal hysteresis.

If you insist on using the Laplace domain. Integrate the output square wave with saturated limits 2~3V from each rail and then reduce range and integrate to get the triangle wave triangle response.
http://fweb.wallawalla.edu/class-wiki/index.php/Laplace_Transform_of_a_Triangle_Wave

But you may find it more awkward.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, relaxation oscillators use a comparator (with push-pull output) as the switching element.  In that case,  Vo has two possibilities (assuming the op-amp is a comparator), VDD or VCC (the rails on the supply powering the comparator, assuming Vpos=VDD, Vneg=VCC).

When Vo goes positive, it charges the capacitor via resistor R. This can be modeled in the Laplace domain as :
[image: ;l]

where \$Vc\_0\$ is the initial voltage across the capacitor -- in this case, \$\frac{VCC}{2}\$ assuming we're starting from \$Vo\$ at \$VCC\$.

The resulting voltage across the cap (presented at the inverting input of the comparator) during this positive charging phase is then: $$V_{cap}(t)=VDD -(VDD+\frac{VCC}{2})\cdot e^{\frac{-t}{R\cdot C}}$$

When \$V_+\$ crosses \$\frac{VCC}{2}\$ (due to the resistor divider created by the wo 6k resistors in your circuit), the output of the comparator will go to the negative rail, \$VCC\$, and the RC network will discharge to that supply voltage.  The model for that phase is similar, the initial condition on the capacitor now being the level the capacitor charged to when the comparator's threshold was crossed.

The frequency of the oscillator is then the inverse of the sum of time to cross each threshold:
$$t_{thd1} = -ln(\frac{2\cdot VDD - VCC}{2\cdot VDD + VCC})\cdot C \cdot R$$ and
$$t_{thd2} = -ln(\frac{2\cdot VCC - VDD}{2\cdot VCC + VDD})\cdot C \cdot R$$

so, $$freq = \frac{1}{t_{thd1}+t_{thd2}}$$.